# files not deletes when using os module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I tried to make a program which delete all of the empty files ( whose size is zero ). Then, i run the program by dragging the script file in "command prompt" and run it .

However, no empty files had deleted (but i have some of them).

Please help me to find the error in my code.

```
import os
a = os.listdir('C:\\Python27')
for folder in a :
  sizes = os.stat('C:\\Python27')
  b = sizes.st_size
  s = folder
  if b == 0 :
    remove('C:\\Python27\s')
```

Comment: You're trying to remove a file named `s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the values iterator `os.listdir` returns to `folder` and yet you aren't using it at all in `os.stat` or `os.remove`, but instead you are passing to them fixed values that you don't need.

You should do something like this:

```
import os
dir = 'C:\\Python27'
for file_name in os.listdir(dir):
    file_path = os.path.join(dir, file_name)
    if os.stat(file_path).st_size == 0:
        os.remove(file_path)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.... I forget to write os before remove..... Your code help me a lot in the join function.... Thank you bro

Answer (score 0):

You can delete something like the following code and you need to add some exception handling. I have used a test folder name to demonstrate.

```
import os
import sys

dir = 'c:/temp/testfolder'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for file in files:
        fname = os.path.join(root, file)
        try:
            if os.path.getsize(fname) == 0:
                print("Removing file %s" %(fname))
                os.remove(fname)
        except:
            print("error: unable to remove 0 byte file")
            raise
```